# Eclipse Hawkbit: Rest API is not working with large file upload

Tags: spring-boot, hawkbit

I am trying [Hawkbit](https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit) for quite some time. By default, it doesn't support upload of software artifacts of more than 1 GB. So I have modified `application-properties` to make it support uploads of more than 1 GB.

Now from UI, I am able to upload file of more than 1 GB size. But from REST API, whenever I try to upload, it shows following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
```

From code of Hawkbit, I got to know that Hawkbit is written on spring boot, but the UI is written in [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/).

Here I am not able to understand, what needs to be provided in case of REST API or some code change is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of this.
By default spring boot multi-part keeps file in memory.
This behavior can be overridden by using following property in place:

> spring.http.multipart.file-size-threshold=1M